# Selecting a subset of data in ServiceStack.OrmLite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Is there any way to return a subset of a table in ServiceStack.OrmLite?
Something like:

```
public class MyStuff
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; } // Some large blob, which is not desired in the list
}

var somestuff = db.Select<MyStuff>(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name });
```

I am really hoping to avoid manual stuff, like "select blabla from somewhere"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had that exact same problem.  Here is what I did:

```
public class MyStuff
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; } 
}

var somestuff = Db.Select<MyStuff>(p => p.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name }));
```

The only changes made, to what you did above, were done to the Db.Select.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for.  They should put this in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation wiki is wide open so feel free to contribute whenever you find something missing.

Answer (score 5):

Create a class for your basic information and set an alias.

```
[Alias("MyStuff")]
public class MyBasicStuff
{
    public Guid Id { get;set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var basicStuff = db.Select<MyBasicStuff>();
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite the dynamic solution I was hoping for, but way better than text based queries.