# ServiceStack Ormlite Select Expression

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am building a service using ServiceStack and using OrmLite to communicate with database. I found following example in [ServiceStack OrmLite Documention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite):

```
db.Select<Author>(q => q.Earnings <= 50);
```

OR

```
db.Select<Author>(q => q.Name.StartsWith("A"));
```

I am trying it with my class User, but unable to find a overload for method "Select" which allows me to do mentioned stuff. In my case q is a linq expression not an instance/reference for generic class type (User in my case). Following is my code:

```
db.Select<User>(q => q.Where(x => x.LastName == "XYZ"));
```

and i want it to be like:

```
db.Select<User>(q => q.LastName == "XYZ");
```

Please let me know if that is an extension method which i am looking for and how can i use that?

Answer (score 0):

The Type that gets selected is the table is looking at, e.g:

```
db.Select<Author>(...) //Author
db.Select<User>(...) //User
```

See the answers on this earlier question for [selecting a subset of data with OrmLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16354147/85785).

Comment: I know the class type would be mapped to a table in DB. Actually i want to fetch List<User> means list of type User. I don't want to fetch a subset of User. Why can't I simply write db.Select<User>(q => q.LastName == "XYZ"); to get a list of type User?

Comment: @Haider You can do exactly that.

Comment: But when i write this statement, intellisense says that q is an instance of linq expression not an instance of type User. So I can only write db.Select<User>(q => q.Where(x => x.LastName == "XYZ")) using q as a linq expression.

Comment: @Haider It's overloaded, you can do both.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in my question. I don't see any overload for this. Am I missing any extension library or any namespace to be included in .cs file for this overload method. BTW I am using ServiceStack.OrmLite 4.0.11.0.

Comment: @Haider You can see some of the [different API examples in the API tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/ApiSqlServerTests.cs).

Comment: I am having this same exact issue.  @mythz - Although you are correct that both will compile, the issue is that visual studio does not provide any intellisense for the db.Select<User>(q => q.LastName == "xyz");.  So, basically when I type "q."  I am not getting the LastName intellisense code completion.  That makes it a huge pain to work with.  When you wrote the example API tests did you have intellisense?

Comment: @Zoran Yes I get intelli-sense for both the `T` and overloaded `SqlExpression<T>` API's, tho not sure if it's because of ReSharper or not.

Comment: @mythz - I have checked the web for Visual Studio Intellisense issues and more specifically Parameter Intellisense issues.  After attempting multiple possible solutions, I haven't been able to get the Intellisense to work properly for this particular issue.  Also, I do not have this issue with any other code.  I am on VS2013 PRO and another developer has also recreated the issue.  Could you try running your VS in SafeMode which should disable any 3rd party tools like ReSharper and see if you see it also?  (Installing ReSharper is not an option for me)

Comment: @mythz - In general I would probably just let this go.  But since the team is transitioning from using EF to using OrmLite, keeping the same/similar syntax is very important.  Although, if one just types it out, it does compile but productivity is lost as it is a pain to have to look at the object every time to figure out how the Property was spelled.  Which, makes it borderline unusable.  Let me know if there is anything else you would like me to try on my end.  Thanks!

Comment: @Zoran Just tried it with ReSharper disabled and the intelli-sense isn't showing up for me either. But I can't see anything in the library I can add to resolve this as removing the overloaded methods from the public API (and breaking existing code-bases) isn't an option. I'll try with the latest 2015 CTP to see if the intelli-sense has improved otherwise I'm not seeing any solution other than reconsidering using R# - IMO C#/VS.NET is unusable without it.

Comment: @Zoran FYI, just finished installing VS 2015 CTP6 where intelli-sense is working, so it should be available when VS 2015 is officially released.

Comment: @Zoran FYI came up with a stop-gap solution you can drop [OrmLiteExtensions.cs](https://gist.github.com/mythz/c9280982d3699ca1c02e) into your project which will provide new API's that will let you get intelli-sense with lambda API's using an 'x' suffix and `SqlExpression<T>` API's by adding a 'q' suffix. You can run with either these API's or delete the 'x' or 'q' after you've completed the statement with intelli-sense to use the official OrmLite API's.

Comment: @mythz Thank you for digging deeper. Since your reply earlier today I have downloaded ReSharper and am making a case for purchasing it for the team.  Although, I am content with VS, your comment about it being unusable without R# resonated with me, where after using it for a few months I will likely feel the same way without it.  Thank you for the OrmLiteExtensions.cs, but that seems like too much of a hack when R# is a cleaner solution even if it is temporary.  BTW, THANK YOU SO MUCH for responding so quickly to SS questions and issues!  It is difficult to convey how much that is appreciated.